# If I buy an Ubuntu tablet, will I be able to use it in the same way as an ubuntu PC?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm looking to buy a new computer. I have noticed that I can get a 2 in 1 computer, with touch features and desktop features, provided by Windows 8. If I install Ubuntu, can I use touch features and desktop features in the one computer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, There are plenty out there. You can check out [**Dell Latitude XT3 laptop**](http://www.dell.com/us/dfb/p/latitude-xt/pd) or [**Inspiron 13 7000 Series**](http://www.dell.com/in/p/inspiron-13-7347-laptop/pd). You can also buy one with Windows and later install Ubuntu on it.